Capybara selenium chromedriver version fail
I was previously successfully writing system tests using Capybara for old Rails project before I try to update the project, thanks to instructions from this solution and Chrome version 114.0.5735.90-1, but a new version of Chrome snuck in there at some point, and the download link now fails with "404. That’s an error." (from https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_114.0.5735.90-1_amd64.deb). Seems the previous fix generally doesn't work any more for whatever reason, noted here. So I try the latest Chrome version (125.0.6422.112) and get:
Failure/Error: Capybara.page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
     
     Webdrivers::NetworkError:
       Net::HTTPServerException: 404 "Not Found" with https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/125.0.6422.112/chromedriver_linux64.zip
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Project is circa 2017. Likely I needed an old Chrome version to match the old gems but cannot recall specifically.
Rails helper:
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, :args => ["--window-size=1920,1080"])
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome

#so can still run rails server
Capybara.server_port = 3000
Capybara.app_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
Spec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller

  # controller spec macros
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller

  # Include Factory Girl syntax to simplify calls to factories
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods 
  
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers, type: :system
  config.after(type: :system) { Warden.test_reset! }
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.filter_run_when_matching focus: true
  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    Capybara.page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
  end
  #databasecleaner code in spec/support/database_cleaning.rb
end

application.rb/environment.rb
Webdrivers::Chromedriver.required_version = "125.0.6422.112"

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 3.6.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.7'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.6.0'
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 1.5"
  gem 'capybara-email'
  etc


per Google,

Each version of ChromeDriver supports Chrome with matching major, minor, and build version numbers. For example, ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.20 supports all Chrome versions that start with 73.0.3683`.

So you must select the right version of Chromedriver for the version of Chrome you're using.
This has always been problematic to manage, and this is why Google introduced the "Chrome for Testing" product, which automatically synchronizes its version with Chrome. (refer to the above link for more info)
I'm curious why you are stuck on version 114 due to Gem compatibility. Mostly Gems affect the server side, I've never encountered a browser incompatibility due to Gems.

Thank you. I do not recall why I was on that Chrome. If it shouldn't matter, why would webdrivers give a 404 acquiring the Chromedriver for the latest Chrome? ... going to assume they're all gone, now with the new Chrome for Testing, and webdrivers is no longer applicable... or I have to somehow manually point it to the Chromedriver file

don't know the answer to that. I seem to recall that Google addresses how to test with Chrome that is not the latest in their docs. But since Chrome updates automatically to the latest, it's probably safe just to test with the latest. At least, that's what I do!

I appreciate that, I will then.  ... any recommendation on how to adjust this project to work with the Chrome for Testing, in its current legacy state, so that I can run rspec without the headless option?

oh yeah, because of some gem dependencies i was stuck on webdrivers 4.1.2, which is capped at 114.0.5735.90, as per this page:  https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html  lolol  ... so i guess i just need to figure out how to install chrome for testing so capybara/selenium uses it, and figure out how to hard code the chromedriver path in there.  start that after a nap
